Is a loop i<n has the same complexity as i<100?
I am trying to understnad if the following codes have the same complexity O(n)?:

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)


i would be happy to hear an explanation too, thank you !
I think that the second loop's complexity is O(n) since in the worst case senario , we run through all the numbers, but my teacher said it's complexity is O(1) and I dont know why


Has at least O(n) (assuming n and i are not modified within the loop and there are no early breaks out of it. 2) is constant time, that is O(1) and there is no dependency on n whatsoever..


2nd example is not dependent on n. So it's O(1).

In the second loop, you do not "run through all the numbers".  You run through the numbers from 0 through 99999.  Every time.  No matter what size the input is.  We might be inclined to think that that's a large number of iterations, but how large or small it is doesn't matter for complexity analysis.  What matters is that the number of iterations is bounded by a constant function.

Keep in mind that Big-O notation talks about asymptotic values, so really really really big values for n. That's why constants factor out. Sure, running a loop that loops 100,000 times multiple times in a row may seem like a lot of operations, but compared to running a much smaller loop n times, it scales better for very large values of n.

Complexity is a measure of how the usage of a resource (CPU time, memory, etc) scales as a variable increases.
The following can be said of the CPU time in terms of n:

The CPU time used increases (at most) linearly with n, so it's O(n).
The CPU time used doesn't increase with n, so it's O(1).


As another exercise, let's compare

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { for(int j=0;j<n;j++) { body(); } }
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { for(int j=i;j<n;j++) { body(); } }

Let's count the number of times body is called.

n2 times.
n+...+3+2+1 = n(n+1)/2 = ½n2 + ½n

So both are O(n2)

The definition of O notation is that A function F(n) is O(f(n)) if there exists an M and an n0 such that, for every n ≥ n0, F(n) ≤ M f(n).
For algorithmic complexity, we are interested a function F(n) that is some measure of how long the algorithm takes, such as the number of steps it takes.
Supposing the loop starting with for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) has some simple body whose time does not depend on n or i and that does not modify n or i, each iteration of the body takes at most some number of steps S. We will include in S the steps required to evaluate i++ and i < n. Then the entire loop takes at most nS steps. So the F we are interested in is F(n) = nS.
This F is O(n): Given n0 = 0 and M = S, it is true that for any n ≥ n0, F(n) ≤ Mn.
Supposing the loop starting with for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) is similarly simple, the entire loop takes at most 100,000 S steps. So the F we are interested in is F(n) = 100,000 S.
This F is O(1): Given n0 = 0 and M = 100,000 S, it is true that for any n ≥ n0, F(n) ≤ M•1.
This F is also O(n), because this definition of the O notation makes it only a kind of “upper bound.” As long as the function stays under the necessary limit, it satisfies the definition. So it is not wrong to say the second loop is O(n). However, that is not the best bound we can give for it; it is stronger to say it is O(1). O notations can also be defined, often using a modified O symbol, to also constrain the function with a lower bound.
